# Oracle to_date raise ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to convert a string containing a date into a date datatype field. Sometime the string is in format *yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss* (FA) and sometime is in format *dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss* (FB).
I am using a small piece of code in order to test, intercept and manage the ORA-01861 but I am facing an unexpected issue. I try to explain.

```
declare
    s varchar2(100) := '2023-02-24 14:22:49';       
    f varchar2(100) := null;
    f1 varchar2(100) := 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
    f2 varchar2(100) := 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
    d date := null;
begin
    f := f1;
    d := to_date(s,f);
    dbms_output.put_line(f||' --> '||d);
    f := f2;
    d := to_date(s,f);
    dbms_output.put_line(f||' --> '||d);
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(s||' --> '||f||' >>>> '||sqlerrm);
end;
```

What I am expecting is that changing the format of **S** the exception is raised due to the unmatching format and in this first example it is what is happening.
The output is:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss --> 24-FEB-23
2023-02-24 14:22:49 --> dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss >>>> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

But if I change the value like this :

```
declare
    s varchar2(100) := '05/03/2023 08:44';
    f varchar2(100) := null;
    f1 varchar2(100) := 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
    f2 varchar2(100) := 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
    d date := null;
begin
    f := f1;
    d := to_date(s,f);
    dbms_output.put_line(f||' --> '||d);
    f := f2;
    d := to_date(s,f);
    dbms_output.put_line(f||' --> '||d);
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(s||' --> '||f||' >>>> '||sqlerrm);
end;
```

There is no exception and the output is:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss --> 20-MAR-05
dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss --> 05-MAR-23
```

I am curious about solutions, workarounds, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do:

```sql
TO_DATE('05/03/2023 08:44', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Then the generated date is `0005-03-20 23:08:44`.

This is because:

- `yyyy` matches `05` (giving the year 5 AD)
- `-` also matches `/` (As the [string-to-date conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5) state "You can use any non-alphanumeric character in the date string to match the punctuation symbol in the format string.")
- `mm` matches `03`
- `-` also matches `/`
- `dd` matches `20`
- The lack of whitespace is ignored
- `hh24` matches `23`
- The extra whitespace is ignored and the lack of `:` is ignored
- `mi` matches `08`; and
- `:` is matched
- `ss` matches `44`.

If you want to raise an exception then use an exact match with the `fx` format model:

```sql
TO_DATE('05/03/2023 08:44', 'fxyyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

And you will get the exception:

```
ORA-01862: the numeric value does not match the length of the format item
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G57SXrpD)

Comment: "As our circle of knowledge expands, so does the circumference of darkness surrounding it." Wow. Never heard of it and it is also well documented. You've really made my day.